# how to center SVG canvas in the window d3.js

Tags: css, svg, d3.js

This is very basic question, so apology in advance. My goal is to center the SVG "canvas" in the center of window. Do I use `.attr()` or do I do with CSS? Any suggestions would be wonderful, thank you. Below is the code where I create my so-called SVG "canvas"..

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", wi + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", h);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommand to not append your SVG directly to the body element but to a wrapper div that you could style in CSS. (with flexbox properties if you also need vertical centering : http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/)

Answer (score 0):

You can either style the SVG directly or wrap the SVG in a div.

Method 1:

```html
let svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", wi + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", h)
            .style("background-color", "lightblue")
            .style("display", "block")
            .style("margin", "auto")
```

If you have lots of styling for the svg, it's preferable to assign a class to it and then define the class using CSS:

```html
let svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", wi + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", h)
            .attr("class", "svg-style")
```

and then

```css
.svg-style {
        background-color: lightblue;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
           }
```

Method 2:

Alternatively, as Delapouite suggested, you may wrap the svg within a div and then style the div (in CSS or directly):

```html
<div id = "demo-div" style="text-align: center">
</div>

let svg = d3.select("#demo-div")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", wi + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", h)
```